# how to only add forward slash after host name if a path exists in url rewrite for IIS 7

Tags: regex, iis-7.5, http-redirect, url-rewrite-module

Using URL Rewrite feature of IIS 7, specifically the redirect portion of it, 
can someone please tell me how to only add a `/` after the host name **only if** a path exists? In other words, I don't want `www.mydomain.biz` to get redirected to `www.mydomain.us/` and prefer `www.mydomain.us` instead without the trailing `/`.

In the "Redirect URL" field (under Action section), it seems that **without** hard coding a `/` in that field to separate any potential path that exists after the host name, I get an error. So I add the forward slash and it works, but then since it's hard coded and when a user goes to `www.mydomain.biz` it redirects to `www.mydomain.us/`.

In the URL Rewrite documentation under [Accessing URL Parts from a Rewrite Rule](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule), it shows the parts as `http(s)://<host>:<port>/<path>?<querystring>` and while the `<path>` is accessible as a regex back reference `{R:0}` it does not include the `/` that precedes it.

[image: Current rule:]

Comment: Your best option would be to use a capturing group to grab the path in a condition, and use the capture group instead of the back reference. Can you post your current rewrite?

Comment: @beavel - see added pic.